# Vite + laravel wildcard input path for production

Tags: laravel, npm, wildcard, vite

I have `vite.config.js` like :

```
export default defineConfig({

  plugins: [
    laravel({
      input: [
        "resources/css/*",
        "resources/js/*",
       ],
      refresh: true,
    }),
```

It only works when I run vite as dev mode using command `npm run dev` or `vite`
but when I run vite in build mode using `npm run build` or `vite build` it will return flowing error

```
Could not resolve entry module "resources/css/*".
error during build:
```

is it possible to use wildcard in vite build mode?

Comment: try doing something like this: `"resources/css/*.css"` and `"resources/js/*.js"`

Comment: same error : 
Could not resolve entry module "resources/css/*.scss".
error during build:

Comment: no error for js? Can you share your folder structure as well please?

Comment: same errror is happening to me

Comment: same problem for js files